# How to solve this error : ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am a beginner in Java EE and spring. Actually I program an application and I spent several hours on an error that I can't correct. I want specify that I look others topic that deals with this exception and I still can't solve it.

I am trying to get a list of Account with this query :

```
    @Override
    public List<Account> getAccountByClient2(Client client){
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"customer id : " + client.getId() );
    List<Account> accounts = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Account a where a.client = :client ")
            .setParameter("client", client)
            .getResultList();
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, " size of the list : " +accounts.size());
    return accounts;
    }
```

This query is on the table `account` which have a foreign key on the table `client` and this table has bean :

**Bean Account**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="account")
    public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "iban")
    private String iban;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_client")
    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    @Column(name="overdraftallowed")
    private Double overdraftallowed;

    @JoinColumn(name="idtypecodeaccount")
    @ManyToOne
    private AccountType accountType;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_balance")
    @ManyToOne
    private Balance balance;
    //getters and setters

    public String toString() {
        return "Account [iban=" + iban + ", overdraftAllowed=" + 
    overdraftallowed + "]";
    }
    }
```

**Bean Client**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="client")
    public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_client")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="statut")
    private String statut;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name="income")
    private float income;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="postal_code")
    private String postal_code;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private String phone_number;

    @Column(name="mail")
    private String mail;

    @Column(name="birthday")
    private Date birthday;

    @Column(name="birthplace_city")
    private String birthplace_city;

    @Column(name="nationality")
    private String nationality;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_status")
    @ManyToOne
    private Status status;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_workgroup")
    @ManyToOne
    private WorkGroup workGroup;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Column(name="abnormal_transaction_service")
    private boolean abnormalTransactionService;

    public Client(String gender, String statut, String first_name, String last_name, float income, String city, String street, String postal_code, String phone_number, String mail, Date birthday, String birthplace_city, String nationality) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.income = income;
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.birthplace_city = birthplace_city;
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }
    //getters and setters

    public void setAbnormalTransactionService(boolean abnormalTransactionService) {
        this.abnormalTransactionService = abnormalTransactionService;
    }
}
```

And this query doesn't work and return this exception on the logs :

```
   [2017-05-30T10:18:16.111+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] 
   [edu.sodteam.dao.AccountDaoImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-
   listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1496132296111] [levelValue: 800] [[
   customer id : 1]]

  [2017-05-30T10:18:16.223+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARN] [] 
  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=23 
  _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1496132296223] [levelValue: 900] 
  [[
  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883]]

  [2017-05-30T10:18:16.224+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [ERROR] [] 
  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=23 
  _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1496132296224] [levelValue: 1000] 
  [[
  ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
  need to add explicit type casts.
  Position : 176]]

  [2017-05-30T10:18:16.227+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] 
  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] [tid: _ThreadID=23 
  _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1496132296227] [levelValue: 800] 
  [[
  HHH000327: Error performing load command : 
  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]]

  [2017-05-30T10:18:16.332+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] 
  [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] 
  [timeMillis: 1496132296332] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[servlet-dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet 
  servlet-dispatcher threw exception
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character 
  varying = integer
  Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
  need to add explicit type casts.
  Position : 176
    at 

 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl
 .java:2182)
    at 
 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:
 1911)
    at 
 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at 
 org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.ds.jdbc23.AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection.java:453)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy246.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1105)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1146)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1005)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:427)
    at edu.sodteam.dao.AccountDaoImpl.getAccountByClient2(AccountDaoImpl.java:116)
    at edu.sodteam.service.ServiceConsultAccount.getCustomerAccount(ServiceConsultAccount.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy826.getCustomerAccount(Unknown Source)
    at edu.sodteam.controller.ConsultAccountController.displayAccount(ConsultAccountController.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

If I understand the error correctly, I try to compare a character varying with integer, but I verified and in my bean as in my database this two columns are integer so I don't understand why it doesn't work. I tried to cast this parameter in integer like this  :

```
   List<Account> accounts = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("from Account a where cast(a.client.id as integer) = :client")
                    .setParameter("client", client.getId())
                    .getResultList();
```

But it doesn't work, so I am completly lost and I hope that someone can help me to fix this problem. Sorry if my english isn't very good and thanks for the people that take the time to read this topic.

**EDITED**

thanks for your answers, here the create query of my table client :

```
CREATE TABLE public.client
(
  id_client integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('client_id_client_seq'::regclass),
  first_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  gender character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  statut character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  income numeric(25,0),
  city character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  street character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  postal_code character varying(5) NOT NULL,
  phone_number character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  mail character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  birthday date,
  birthplace_city character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  nationality character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  abnormal_transaction_service boolean,
  id_user integer NOT NULL,
  id_status integer NOT NULL,
  id_workgroup integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT prk_constraint_client PRIMARY KEY (id_client),
  CONSTRAINT fk_client_id_status FOREIGN KEY (id_status)
      REFERENCES public.status (id_status) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_client_id_user FOREIGN KEY (id_user)
      REFERENCES public."user" (id_user) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_client_id_workgroup FOREIGN KEY (id_workgroup)
      REFERENCES public.workgroup (id_workgroup) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT client_mail_key UNIQUE (mail)
)
```

As you can see it is an integer and i verified for the table account  it's an integer too. I tried to write the query completely whithout use the setparameter but it's still the same problem.

Comment: Looks like the problem is extracting results not passing parameter.

Comment: Does your `account` Table has the FK `id_client`?

Comment: Please post the definition of your `client` **table**. Your error message suggests that its primary key (`id_client`) is defined as `character varying` (instead of `integer`).

Comment: Your approach *should* work. However, you may also try to match the id explicitly: `.createQuery("from Account a JOIN Client c where c.id = :client_id ").setParameter("client_id", client.getId())`.

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to try your solution @JimmyB becaus I don't undertsand why actually it doesn't work

Comment: @JimmyB : Unfortunately I have the same error with your query, thanks for your solution.

Comment: @kism3t : Yes in my account table I have a FK on id_client